# java - how to pass multiple parameters over serial port to Arduino mega

Tags: java, serial-port, arduino

Through my java program. i want to pass a byte value to the Arduino mega to blink an Led
and also at the same time i want to pass a string value to the Arduino to be displayed in the lcd.

How can I separately get above 2 inputs from the java program to Arduino and use them in different processes inside Arduino..

### Below is the arduino code

```
LiquidCrystal lcd (12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7);
int operation;

void setup() {

lcd.begin(16, 2);


Serial.begin(9600);
Serial1.begin(9600);
Serial2.begin(9600);

pinMode(3, OUTPUT);
pinMode(2, OUTPUT);

}

int count = 0; 
void loop() {

//LCD start
if (Serial.available()) {
// wait a bit for the entire message to arrive
delay(50);
// clear the screen
lcd.clear();
delay(10);
// read all the available characters
while (Serial.available() > 0) {
  // display each character to the LCD
  lcd.write(Serial.read());
 }
 } 
 //LCD end

 //LED Blink start
 if (Serial.available() > 0)
 delay(10);
 {
 operation = Serial.read();
  }

 if(operation == '2')
 {

  digitalWrite(2, LOW);
  digitalWrite(3, HIGH);
  delay(50);
  digitalWrite(3, LOW);
  delay(50);
  }

  if(operation == '1')
  {

   digitalWrite(3, LOW);
   digitalWrite(2, HIGH);
   delay(50);
   digitalWrite(2, LOW);
   delay(50);
 }
  //LED Blink end

  // Recieve rfid tag numbers 
if(Serial1.available()) { 
   int x = Serial1.read();     
   Serial1.print(x);
  }

if(Serial2.available()) { 
   int x = Serial2.read();     
   Serial1.print(x);
  }

}
```

### Below is the Java code to send data

Code to send number 1 to Arduino

```
String buf = "1";
char buf2[] = buf.toCharArray();
output.write((byte)buf2[0]);
```

Code to send string to display in lcd

```
output.write("Hellow world. this is a String from java".getBytes());
```

### When I run these codes separately it works well without any interference.. but when I do them both together... sometimes value 1 or 2 is displayed in the lcd.. and led doesnot blink properly . how to get two inputs from java to arduino and process them separately inside the Arduino?

Answer (score 0):

I think there might be several issues working in concert.

**First** of all, Strings are represented internally in Java as UTF-16 encoded characters. I don't remember what Arduino "C" operates on per default, but I am pretty sure it is not UTF-16.

From the JavaDoc

> "A String represents a string in the UTF-16 format in which
>   supplementary characters are represented by surrogate pairs (see the
>   section Unicode Character Representations in the Character class for
>   more information). Index values refer to char code units, so a
>   supplementary character uses two positions in a String."

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

**Second**,
the method getBytes() return a platform specific encoded array, so depending on what platform you run the program on, the returned bytes can vary.

**Try** looking into using `public byte[] getBytes(String charsetName)`, which will give you predictable values back.

Try something like `bytes[] asciiBytes = new String("Hello World").getBytes("US-ASCII");`.

See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html for more info on Character sets.

Comment: Thanks brother.. but my problem is not that... My system works well.. I successfully passed data to Arduino.. But my issue is, I want to pass two values at the same time to the Arduino. and inside the Arduino I want to get those 2 values seperately, but i didnt find any way for that. arduino usually reads thee serial data comming from pc by just 1 command , that is "serial.read". So how can I get those 2 values separately to the Arduino?

Comment: Understand. See comment form Richard210363. Concatenation and separation in Arduino is the best way then.

Answer (score 0):

You could concatenate the data.
So, if you are passing "Hello" and "200" as 2 items then combine them before the send to Arduino and send "Hello%200" and split on the % inside the Arduino.

Comment: How to split the concatenated incoming String inside the Arduino? That is my problem

Comment: separatorPosition = message.indexOf('%');

if (separatorPosition != -1)
{
 string uiMessage = message.substring(0,separatorPosition ));
 string duration = message.substring(separatorPosition +1, message.length());
}